# Outputting a group ring values using two for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm learning Java and I seem to be very weak in my knowledge of for loops.

I am supposed to call `printSquare(1, 5);`. The output I want is:

```
12345
23451
34512
45123
51234
```

I tried out:

```
public void printSquare(int min,int max){

    for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){
        for(int j=i;j<=max;j++){
          System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

which gives me:

```
12345
2345
345
45
5
```

I then tried inserting 2 more loops but it does not seem to work.

I would appreciate it if you don't give me the full answer, because that is not the way to learn. I would prefer some clues on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Look up the modulo operator, %, in Java. In particular see what j % 5 does

Comment: Note that the inner loop has to run constant no. of times always. And also that the printing a set of nos. always start from i, then go up to max and then again start from 1. Try to use the mod operator for this task.

Comment: I am familar with this.modulo gives the remainder.i think i roughly know how to modify.

Comment: Sorry.i am still pretty lost.I am thinking of placing j%5 outside of my loops.But if j=5%5,doesn't it print 0 instead of 1?

Comment: @user2179615 If j%5 will print 01234 and you want 12345, what's a trivial arithmetic operation we could apply to get from the former to the latter?

Comment: your loop does exactly what you ordered it to do. You have a wrong algorithm for that (if it can be called an algorithm already). Think some more. ... or read the ready-made solutions below. Hope you at least learn something from them

Comment: check out @ArunPJohny's answer. Superb programming. Try to programm like that.

Answer (score 2):

You should add one more loop nested into the `i` loop, but outside the `j` loop.

It should be from `min` to `i-1`.

Comment: This is where i am not sure.Regarding when the loop need to be nested.Because things get so complicated for me when i see so many loops

Comment: It should NOT be nested inside the `j` loop. If it is nested inside the `j` loop this means: for every `j` iteration do another loop. This is not correct. But it is nested inside the `i` loop, because for every row iteration we want this logic.

Comment: @PetarMinchev He means inside the i loop. Outside the j loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public static void printSquare(int min, int max) {

    int x = max - min + 1;

    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        int counter = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            System.out.print(counter);
            counter = counter >= max ? min : counter + 1;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if the case is say, `printSquare(0, 5);`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny - this is the best answer IMHO. Lesser steps, superb reasult.

Comment: @Saurabh indeed less steps, the result.. well, it is not superb. check my answer also

Answer (score 1):

i think you can try a second loop within i outside j

```
public void printSquare(int min,int max){

    for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){

        for(int j=i;j<=max;j++){
          System.out.print(j);
        }
        for(int k=min;k<i;k++){
          System.out.print(k);
        }

    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems that from 8 answers you got your solution. :)

I only wanted to test this to see which would be faster(mine) or the 3 loops method.

Here is the code(you don't have to understand it by any means), except one method - **printSquare(int number)** that is the only that is relevant to you. The rest has to do with caliper framework- I used it to measure some results.

```
import com.google.caliper.Param;
import com.google.caliper.Runner;
import com.google.caliper.SimpleBenchmark;



public class Measure extends SimpleBenchmark {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Runner.main(Measure.class, args);
     }

     @Param({"1"})
     private int mins;

     @Param({"4","7","9"})
     private int maxs;

    public void timePrintSquare3Loops(int reps){
        for(int i=0;i<reps;++i){
            printSquareTwo(mins, maxs);
        }
    }

    public void timePrintSquareMine(int reps){
        for(int i=0;i<reps;++i){
            printSquareOne(mins, maxs);
        }
    }

    public void timePrintSquareTwoLoops(int reps){
        for(int i=0;i<reps;++i){
            printSquareTwoLoops(mins, maxs);
        }
    }


    /**
     * the general solution with 3 loops
     */
     public void printSquareTwo(int min,int max){
         for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){
             for(int j=i;j<=max;j++) System.out.print(j);
             for(int k=min;k<i;k++)  System.out.print(k);           
         }
     }

    public static void printSquareTwoLoops(int min, int max) {
        int x = max - min + 1;
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            int counter = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) { 
                System.out.print(counter);
                counter = counter >= max ? min : counter + 1;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * If you know the number upfront. for example 345678.
     *    345678-3*10000=45678=>most significatDigit=3, difference = 45678. 
     *    number = 45678*10 + significatDigit=456783
     *    
     *    And so on..
     * 
     */
     public void printSquareOne(int min, int max){
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         for(int i=min;i<=max;++i){sb.append(i);}
             int number = Integer.valueOf(sb.toString());
             int howMany = (""+number).length();        
             for(int i=0;i<howMany;++i){
                 int pow = (int)Math.pow(10, (howMany-1));
                 int mostSignificantDigit = 0;
                 int intermediarResult = number;
                 do {
                     ++mostSignificantDigit;
                     intermediarResult = intermediarResult - pow;
                 } while (intermediarResult>pow);
                 number = intermediarResult * 10 + mostSignificantDigit;
                 System.out.println(number);
            }    
     }
}
```

And I run a few tests.

**EDIT** I also added @Arun P Johny method to the tests.

Here is the output:

```
 4      PrintSquare3Loops  32.4 =====
 4        PrintSquareMine  20.7 ===
 4    PrintSquareTwoLoops  38.4 ======
 4 PrintSquareCollections  31.8 =====
 7      PrintSquare3Loops  92.9 ==============
 7        PrintSquareMine  36.8 =====
 7    PrintSquareTwoLoops 102.6 ================
 7 PrintSquareCollections 104.8 ================
 9      PrintSquare3Loops 166.2 ==========================
 9        PrintSquareMine  41.7 ======
 9    PrintSquareTwoLoops 187.5 ==============================
 9 PrintSquareCollections 147.7 =======================
```

Seems like 3 loops one after another are not that good for performance. I an talking about memory here, I am sure that mine will use more.

Comment: Dear @Eugene, I tried to test your code. Its not working. printSquareOne(1, 5) prints out 2341
3412
4123
1234

Comment: @Saurabh ups! small typo here : for(int i=min;i<=max;++i). Notice the <= as opposed to =

Comment: Add mine to this benchmark if you have spare time - I wonder how the other approach fares. I think it will be slower.

Comment: Thx. It's not bad, I though the list access/push/pop overhead will be more significant.

Answer (score 0):

see this logic, it does the required operation, it is generic would work for any +ve value of min, max:

```
for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){
    for(int j=min;j<=max;j++){
        int val = (j + i - min);
            if (val >max ){
                val -= max - min + 1;
            }
            System.out.print(val);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't approve giving students full implementation, but this time I have done something differently than the OP suggested. Hope he learns something.

```
public class RingGroupPrint {
  public static void printSquare(int min,int max){
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int a=min; a<=max; a++) {
      list.add(a);
    }

    for (int i= 0, amount = max-min +1; i<amount; i++ ){
      for (Integer val: list) {
        System.out.print(val);
      }
      list.offerLast(list.pollFirst());
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printSquare(1, 5);
  }
}
```

I don't claim it's optimal or better than a straightforward 2 for's implementation. It uses Java's collections and is a good learning material. I hope.

Answer (score -1):

Add another loop in your code.
Try this:

```
public void printSquare(int min, int max) {
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            int j = i;
            for (j = i; j <= max; j++) {
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            for (int k = j - i, l = min; k < max; k++, l++) {
                System.out.print(l);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
}
```